# How to assign values from 1 column to another with warning in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DF with 56 columns. 2 of those columns(X and Y) are empty and I would like to duplicate values stored in 2 different columns in the same DF. Right now, I managed to do it, but I get a warning :

*A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead*

I tried this version as well, but still get the caveat warning. Here's my syntax so far :

```
subset = df[(df.Longitude.isnull()) & (df.Latitude.isnull())]
subset.Longitude = subset.x2
subset.Latitude = subset.y2
```

Any idea on how to do this without getting the warning notification? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `fillna`

This is how you should be doing it.  Pass a dictionary to `fillna` specifying what to fill each column with.  The keys of the dictionary are mapped to column names.  So below, fill the missing values of the `'Longitude'` column with corresponding values from `df.x2`.

```
df.fillna({'Longitude': df.x2, 'Latitude': df.y2})
```

---

#### `loc`

But to answer your question and barring any other issues.

```
mask = df.Longitude.isna() & df.Latitude.isna()
df.loc[mask, ['Longitude', 'Latitude']] = df.loc[mask, ['x2', 'y2']].to_numpy()
```

---

#### Not super useful

Because most people find this difficult to read

```
mask = df.Longitude.isna() & df.Latitude.isna()
df.loc[mask, 'Longitude'], df.loc[mask, 'Latitude'] = map(df.get, ['x2', 'y2'])

df
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. Could you explain a bit more on the .fillna if possible?

Comment: See if that helps.